# How use a API call with discord.py?

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I'm using an API in python and when **I make a request to this API, the server must send a audio mensage in a channel.**

In a text channel I use a webhook, that gives me the context of the channel. I need something like that to be abble to play the audio.

**There is any way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can not play the audio file after sending it through bot.

What you can do is download the audio file and play it using FFMPEG

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, every time you send an API call, you wish to send a sound clip to a channel?

if this is the case this should be quite simple, in your API function, after you make the API call, you should create an if statement to check that the API return is 200, after that you should use VoiceState to get the current voice channel of the user, or you can simply hardcode the voice channel id in your code.

a headstart might look something like this.

```
voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
vc = await voice_channel.connect()
vc = ctx.voice_client
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source='your_file.mp3'))
await asyncio.sleep(5) # alter this depending upon how long your file will be
await vc.disconnect()
```

note, using this method you will need to import asyncio to the top of your file and you will need to download the FFMPEG and link it using this portion of the code

```
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source='your_file.mp3'))
```

if you need to know how to see if you got a 200 response using your API one way to do it is

```
if APIReq.status_code == 200:
    print("Status Code: " + str(APIReq.status_code))
```

where APIReq is equal to your requests.get variable name for your API call.

does this help you get started?